# Layout switcher for product view magento 2.3.5 (Custom layout update)

Tags: magento2.3, page-layouts, custom-layout-update

Since the update to Magento 2.3.x it is possible to change the layout of the product output using a product id or sku:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/product-layouts.html
- https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-add-the-custom-layout-update-on-magento-2.html

Unfortunately there is no possibility to give different designs generally for product types with custom layout update like:

```
catalog_product_view_selectable_<to-all-products>_<layout-name>.xml
```

Is there any other way to control the design of the product output in admin?

As an example I would need for the bundle product three different layouts in the frontend, which layout should be loaded controllable via admin in the product itself.

Comment: Similar to: [https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26901](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26901)

Comment: Try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/328120/82670

Answer (score 0):

Follow this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/328120/82670

You can add how your layout looks into customlayout_index_index.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend/layout.

Update  CustomLayoutHandler.php file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/Observer code.

You can create multiple layouts and check into the Observer file.

[Demo Module Click here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oyEkzFKpHtNuKA6N90gV5YF7NNdwQdJD)