# Magento 2: Add CSS / JS to custom layout - only applied to single page

Tags: magento2, layout, css, less

I have a custom page layout for Home Page.

I created this custom layout this way:

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="custom">
        <label translate="true">custom layout</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/page_layout/custom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

How can I add CSS only to this layout? (not through default_head_blocks.xml). This has to show up only on that page and only on that layout?

The only way that worked for me was through Admin interface via:

But, I would like to do this via XML. Is this possible?

You used to be able to do this in Magento 1 with add css with actions

```
<action method="addCss">
    <stylesheet>css/javcustom.css</stylesheet>
</action>
```

Is there something like that in Magento 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **First we create a custom layout, after that we add custom CSS and JS to this custom layout.**

> **Step-1 :Create layouts.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend and add below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="customlayout">
        <label translate="true">Custom CMS Page</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

***File name must be layout id name. Now we create customlayout.xml***

> **Step-2 : Create customlayout.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend/page_layout and add below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="3columns"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="footer-bottom" as="footer-bottom" after="footer" label="Footer Bottom" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer-bottom">
            <container name="footer-bottom-content" as="footer-bottom-content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="report.bugs.bottom" template="Magento_Theme::html/bugreport.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

*You can also add your custom block and phtml file also. which are shown in Layouts when custom layout is used.*

*Now we add CSS and Js to custom layout file*

> **Step-3 : Create routes.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/etc/frontend and add below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="customlayout" id="customlayout">
            <module name="VendoreName_CustomLayout"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> **Step-4 : Create Index.php file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/Controller/Index and add below code.**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomLayout\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

> **Step-5 : Create customlayout_index_index.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend/layout and add below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="VendoreName_CustomLayout::css/my_custom_layout_css.css" />
        <script src="VendoreName_CustomLayout::js/my_custom_layout_js.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

**Here the file name must be like routename_controllername_actionname.xml and all characters must be in lowercase.**

***Add your css to app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend/web/css/my_custom_layout_css.css***

***Add your Js to app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend/web/js/my_custom_layout_js.js***

> **Step-6 : Create events.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/etc and add below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="custom_layout_css_js_add" instance="VendoreName\CustomLayout\Observer\CustomLayoutHandler" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**we need to add to css and js before page layout that's why we use layout_load_before event.**

> **Step-7 : Create CustomLayoutHandler.php file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/Observer and add below code.**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomLayout\Observer;

class CustomLayoutHandler implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $pageResult,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page
    ) {
        $this->_pageResult = $pageResult;
        $this->_page = $page;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getData('layout');
        $currentPageLayout = $this->_pageResult->getConfig()->getPageLayout();
        //$currentPageLayout = $this->_page->getPageLayout();
        if ($currentPageLayout == "customlayout") {
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customlayout_index_index');
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Doesnt work. I created the folder structure and all the files exactly how you mentioned under /vendor folder(instead of app). Nothing shows up in dropdown. 

vendor/testvendor/CustomLayout/Controller/Index/Index.php
vendor/testvendor/CustomLayout/etc/events.xml
vendor/testvendor/CustomLayout/etc/frontend/routes.xml
vendor/testvendor/CustomLayout/Observer/CustomLayoutHandler.php
vendor/testvendor/CustomLayout/view/frontend/layouts.xml
vendor/testvendor/CustomLayout/view/frontend/page_layout/customlayout.xml
vendor/testvendor/CustomLayout/view/frontend/layout/customlayout_index_index.xml

Comment: How can I debug something like this? Are the errors that say why module doesnt work?

Comment: you have to create module into app/code folder.

Comment: Please download this https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oyEkzFKpHtNuKA6N90gV5YF7NNdwQdJD?usp=sharing . then update me.

Comment: Before using my module please remove your created files from it. and don't forgot to run magento setup upgrade command before check it.

Comment: Thanks I'll test it on monday! I was running all the upgrade / compile commands, but it would still not show it. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Please download module and install it. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oyEkzFKpHtNuKA6N90gV5YF7NNdwQdJD

Comment: I am getting an error: "1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (OutOfBoundsException): The element with the "page.wrapper_schedule_block0" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again." Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: (this happens when you visit Admin Page)

Comment: you can check area use this 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state =  $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
echo $state->getAreaCode();  if you get any issue related to admin side.

Comment: for check area  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/241076/82670

Comment: I don't understand. When I deploy your code as you supplied it(zip file) I get an error: "1 exception(s): Exception #0 (OutOfBoundsException): The element with the "page.wrapper_schedule_block0" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again." Have you tried your code?

Comment: it's error show when you run upgrade command. after run this command clear cache and just refresh you page.

Comment: Does not work after running upgdade/compile/generate/flush, I ran all the commands. Can you please test your plugin?

Comment: Please share your error and code also. and i am not used plugin. please check your code.