# Custom layout update not working 2.4

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.1, custom-layout-update

I have made the custom category layout update named as `catalog_category_view_selectable_3_Test.xml` in **Magento_Catalog/layout**.

When I checked in admin panel in custom layout update the options is not showing.

[image]

Kindly provide a solution to custom layout update for category for magento 2.4.

Comment: hi there, can you also share the content of your custom layout file?

Comment: Sure @DianaBotean 

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: looks good, i can't see anything wrong with that content.

Comment: @DianaBotean yes, but the custom update handle is not working. Any possible other solutions?

Comment: at the moment i don't see anything wrong with the content or the filename tbh. did you try to add this for another category ID? see if the behavior is still the same?

Comment: @DianaBotean I have tried it with other categories too but it didn't work.

Comment: sorry to hear this, very interesting behavior indeed.

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/328120/82670

Answer (score 4):

I had some "issue" with Magento-2.4.2 and I had spent about 2 hours before I understood what I was Pinocchio  )) I was checking the wrong scope - **All Stores Views** instead of **current store with applied theme** ))).
Maybe my bad experiences save time anybody

Answer (score 1):

If the custom selectable layout is not being shown in the custom layout dropdown then the layout file is not being recognized.

Make sure your `catalog_category_view_selectable_3_Test.xml` file does not have any additional or trailing spaces in the filename.

Tested with 2.4.2

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view_selectable_3_Test.xml
```

[image]

If you can't see the option in the dropdown, then try after clearing the cache.

Comment: Hey @Paj , The file name doesn't have any additional space or trailing spaces in the filename.

Comment: I tested the exact same filename on 2.4.2 and it worked correctly. Are you adding this to a theme or module? I tested with App/Design/FrontendVendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view_selectable_3_Test.xml

Comment: I have added it in the theme.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to: [How to add/update custom layout update on magento 2.3.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302775/how-to-add-update-custom-layout-update-on-magento-2-3-4/311542#311542)

I am using the Porto child theme on 2.4.2 and the no options were displayed in the category Custom Layout Dropdown (Not even - No Update). Applied @Marrbacca solution and it got the options to display - although so far, the selection does not seem to behave an effect on the frontend. :/